# Alternative aproach to fetching images from shopify API (Performance issue)

Tags: c#, shopify

Always dubious posting a question like but I feel Shopify's process to fetching images hinders our process.

Initial testing with the current logic it takes our system round about 2.3 minutes to process 50 orders, now if I remove the logic to fetch images (not physical images - image obj) it takes **2-3 seconds**

Now with the logic yes, it's in a loop, so for each product get the `variant_id` and then call the `ProductVariant API`

50 orders, 2 products in each order(more or less) ... I'm sure you see the pattern here and the number of calls required.

Having scanned the docs vigorously, shopify doesn't seem supply enough information on the order to limit this.

An order has Line Items (Products) and each product has multiple variants (Color, Size, image_id) etc, But the `variant_id` assigned to the `line_item` would be the physical values of the variant.

A little code, to give a better understanding...

```
foreach (var l in productLineItems)
{

   var mainImageSRC = "";
   var productVariant = ProductVariant(l.Variant_Id);
   if (productVariant != null)
    {
      if (productVariant.image_id != null)
       {
         var imageId = productVariant.image_id;
         mainImageSRC = ImageById(l.Product_Id, productVariant.image_id).Src;
       }
       else
        {
           mainImageSRC = Images(l.Product_Id).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Position == "1").Src;
        }
     }
}
```

The end result is that I have to grab the image, if a variant does not exist, I grab a collection of images, using the `product_id` and then find the main image with the `position` property.

I suppose the performance issue is the ridiculous amount of calls to get the image.

Hopefully I'm doing something wrong here, to finally shed some light on a better approach.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: No caching what so-ever, it's supposed to be a quick stream-line process. Which it is, without fetching the image details

Comment: How often does this code execute a day? Once? Ten times? 1000 times?

Comment: Every 10 seconds, not factoring in large volumes or orders - meaning a paging facility times by the limit to get number of pages... hence multiple calls in one cycle.

Comment: I take it that `ImageById` is the slow call? If so, you could cache the results of that call into a `MemoryCache` (or `ConcurrentDictionary`) - so that the first hit is slow but subsequent lookups are very fast.

Comment: No it's actually  - var productVariant = ProductVariant(l.Variant_Id); Poor naming convention should be "GetProductVariant". But duly noted, I'll look into that. Must be a better approach to getting the image(main image)

Comment: @mjwills I've managed to get this down to around 42 seconds per 50 orders - still not good enough but closer. So removed the product variant call... Got all images to associated to a product (which contains variant Ids) then did a lookup on the product to grab the variant... then compared ...

Comment: var images = GetImages(l.Product_Id); if (images.Any(x => x.Variant_Ids != null 
                                            && x.Variant_Ids.Count > 0))
                            {

                                mainImageSRC = images.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Variant_Ids.Contains(l.Variant_Id)).Src;
                            }

Comment: If `ProductVariant` is the slow part of the code, could you include that code in your question?

Comment: @mjwills sure thing... I'm going to run tests this evening with the refactored version and then update the question.